# Having Appended Fields Contain Unique Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fairly complicated form that I have simplified for the purpose of demonstration.

I would like to be able to add an "item" via a button on a form. This part wasn't too hard. I then am trying to modify each independent item via a drop down. However, the current method of altering options is through the class each one is assigned. When two classes are similar, both will be adjusted through one drop down.

Is there a way to assign a unique class when the new field is generated?

Thank you!

```
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
function changeMenu(value){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".change").css("display","none");
        if(value=="hardware"){
            $(".hardware").show();
            };
        if(value=="production"){
            $(".production").show();
            };
        if(value=="design"){
            $(".design").show();
            };
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper             = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="input_fields_wrap"> <label for="item_type">Item Type: </label><br /> <select id="change[]" onchange="changeMenu(this.value)"> <option value="">Select</option> <option value="production">Production</option> <option value="design">Design</option> <option value="hardware">Harware Only</option> <option value="outsource">Outsourced</option> <option value="install">Installation</option> </select> <div class="change production" style="display:none"> <label for="item_size">Size: </label><br /> <input type="number" name="production_width[]" id="item_width" autocomplete="off" style="width: 50px" value="0" /> </div> <div class="change design" style="display:none"> <label for="item_size">Dize: </label><br /> <input type="number" name="design_width[]" id="item_width" autocomplete="off" style="width: 60px" value="0" /> </div> </div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});



</script>
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="input_fields_wrap">

        <label for="item_type">Item Type: </label><br />
        <select id="change[]" onchange="changeMenu(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="production">Production</option>
            <option value="design">Design</option>
            <option value="hardware">Harware Only</option>
            <option value="outsource">Outsourced</option>
            <option value="install">Installation</option>
        </select>


    <div class="change production" style="display:none">
        <label for="item_size">Size: </label><br />
        <input type="number" name="production_width[]" id="item_width" autocomplete="off" style="width: 50px" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div class="change design" style="display:none">
        <label for="item_size">Dize: </label><br />
        <input type="number" name="design_width[]" id="item_width" autocomplete="off" style="width: 60px" value="0" />
    </div>
</div>
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
```

Comment: Do you mind making a jsfiddle so I can see the code in action? (And hopefully better understand what you want)

Comment: I'm trying. For some reason it isn't working the same as it is on my server. Bear with me for a few...

Comment: Your `wrapper `, `add_button` etc are already jquery objects, you don't have to create another one by wrapping them again in `$()` like `$(add_button)`

Comment: *"Is there a way to assign a unique class when the new field is generated"* - i don't think that's the right way to do it... classes are used to group common items together, not to  uniquely identify an item - for that use an `id`. I'm pretty sure this is an xy problem. If you explain what you're actually trying to do, there might be a better alternative way...

Answer (score 0):

I have clean up your code a little bit, i think its working now. I have removed `function changeMenu`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="input_fields_wrap">
  <div class="input_fields_wrap">

          <label for="item_type">Item Type: </label><br />
          <select id="change[]">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="production">Production</option>
              <option value="design">Design</option>
              <option value="hardware">Harware Only</option>
              <option value="outsource">Outsourced</option>
              <option value="install">Installation</option>
          </select>


      <div class="change production" style="display:none">
          <label for="item_size">Size: </label><br />
          <input type="number" name="production_width[]" id="item_width" autocomplete="off" style="width: 50px" value="0" />
      </div>

      <div class="change design" style="display:none">
          <label for="item_size">Dize: </label><br />
          <input type="number" name="design_width[]" id="item_width" autocomplete="off" style="width: 60px" value="0" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper             = $("#input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count

  $('#input_fields_wrap').on("change","select", function(e){ 
    $(".change").css("display","none");
    var fieldWrap = $(this).closest('.input_fields_wrap');
    fieldWrap.find("." + $(this).val()).show();
  });

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="input_fields_wrap"> <label for="item_type">Item Type: </label><br /> <select id="change[]"> <option value="">Select</option> <option value="production">Production</option> <option value="design">Design</option> <option value="hardware">Harware Only</option> <option value="outsource">Outsourced</option> <option value="install">Installation</option> </select> <div class="change production" style="display:none"> <label for="item_size">Size: </label><br /> <input type="number" name="production_width[]" id="item_width" autocomplete="off" style="width: 50px" value="0" /> </div> <div class="change design" style="display:none"> <label for="item_size">Dize: </label><br /> <input type="number" name="design_width[]" id="item_width" autocomplete="off" style="width: 60px" value="0" /> </div> </div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Demo:

http://code-chunk.com/chunks/543a233611342/select-product-from-drop-down-menu

Comment: Thank you for the help. It doesn't function as intended though. What should happen is the first element remains with all information, and if a second is added and elements are changed it doesn't effect the first. Trying to find a better way to illustrate this, as I realize my original post is lacking in clarity.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ya84hoy9/3/

Your approach to the problem looks wrong to me. So I've change it quite a bit. I've created a template of the field:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap" style="display:none;" id="field_template">

    <label>Item Type: </label><br />
    <select class="select-change">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="production">Production</option>
        <option value="design">Design</option>
        <option value="hardware">Harware Only</option>
        <option value="outsource">Outsourced</option>
        <option value="install">Installation</option>
    </select>

    <div class="change production" style="display:none">
        <label>Size: </label><br />
        <input type="number" name="production_width[]" autocomplete="off" style="width: 50px" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div class="change design" style="display:none">
        <label>Dize: </label><br />
        <input type="number" name="design_width[]" autocomplete="off" style="width: 60px" value="0" />
    </div>
        <button class="remove_field">x</button>
</div>
```

it should be outside the form

And I've added a placeholder for the fields:

```
<div id="fields">      
</div>
```

it should be inside the form.

```
$(function() {
    function changeMenu(el){
        $(el).closest('.input_fields_wrap').find(".change").css("display","none");
        $(el).closest('.input_fields_wrap').find("." + el.value).show();
    };

    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var template             = $("#field_template");
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    addField();
    add_button.click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            addField();
        }
    });

    function addField() {
        var clone = $('#field_template').clone();
        $('#fields').append(clone.removeAttr('id').show());
    }

    $('#fields').on('change', '.select-change',function(){changeMenu(this);})

    $('#fields').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if(x >1){
         $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        }
    })
});
```

the code clones the template and puts in the placeholder

Comment: This appears to work great. Thank you! The approach is more sensible as well.